# Issue while using requestFocus on EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

I'm having an issue when i'm trying to requestFocus by using a physical enter keyboard from a Honeywell Eda60K device and other.

If i press "Confirm" view button it's focus editText fine but if i use enter button it doesn't focus the next editText as you can see on this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WkfOgl19CQ)

Here is my OnEditorActionListener method from one of two editText

```
 public void codeText(){
        code.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if(i == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE || keyEvent != null && KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER == keyEvent.getKeyCode()){
                    if(!code.getText().toString().equals("")){
                        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(code.getText())) {
                            if (code.getText().length() >= 1 && code.getText().length() <= 999999) {
                                if(qtaBox.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                                    qtaBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    qtaText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    qta.requestFocus();
                                }else {
                                    qta.requestFocus();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```